# magento getting the sub sub category ID in product list page

Tags: magento

I need to add CMS page in product listing page ONLY FOR A PARTICULAR `sub-sub-category = 35`. The way I tried is by editing the `view.phtml`.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('adminCMSid')->toHtml()
```

But I need to compare in view.phtml if the current product has a Sub-Sub-Category equal to 35.
Could someone help me how to get the current sub-sub-category ID and solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

in `catalog/view.phtml`:

```
<?php
    $_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 

    foreach($_categories as $category){
        if($category == 35){
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('adminCMSid')->toHtml();
            break; //stop the loop
        }
    }
?>
```

**Long answer:**

If you want to find the data that is currently available inside a template file, for example in `view.phtml` for `$_product` you can insert this:

```
<?php Mage::log(print_r($_product->debug(), true), null, 'finddata.log', true); ?>
```

Refresh the product page and then go into var/logs folder and you will find the finddata.log file.
There you can see the categories for that product and the array details that you can use.

Then you can do something like this:

```
$_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
var_dump($_categories);
```

This will give you the array of categories for that given product. Like this it is easier to test and find out your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>

<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
    <?php if ($_category->getId() == 35) {
        //Subcategory id equals 35
    }?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I did not get it to work with $this-> getCurrentChildCategories().

Comment: On reviewing this you'd have to be in catalog/product/list.phtml to get this to work. Just another approach to what Claudiu posted above, you'll find that magneto has many wonderful methods, hope this helps someone else in the future :-)